# Vertically aligning a header that uses text and a graphic for a basic jQuery accordion effect

Tags: jquery, css

I am really struggling with getting some basic formatting right for this jQuery accordion (that I based the code from [this example](http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/create-accordian-boxes-with-a-rotating-arrow-using-css-jquery)).

**I am trying to get the following effect (note the spacing and vertical alignment):**

[image]

**Yet I end up with this:**

[image]

**This is what I am currently trying:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LmG3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">TIME</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">CREATIVITY</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">BUDGET</h2></div>
<div class="content"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam turpis urna, tristique quis convallis nec, dapibus sed velit.</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title {
    padding-left:15px;
    height:17px;
    background: url('http://www.elevate1.co.uk/dropdownwitharrows/images/arrow-toggle.png') 0 3px  no-repeat  !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.on {
    background: url('http://www.elevate1.co.uk/dropdownwitharrows/images/arrow-toggle.png') 0 -12px  no-repeat  !important;
}
.content {
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.title').click(function() {
        $('.title').removeClass('on');
        $('.content').slideUp('normal');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main problem is your img, it should be a little smaller(its dimensions i mean). any way
i changed **only** your first title

```
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png">TIME</h2></div>
```

TO

```
<div class="title"><h2><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XsDSYw6.png"><span>TIME</span></h2></div>
```

and in your css:

```
.title {
    padding-left:15px;
    height:17px;
    background: transparent url('http://www.elevate1.co.uk/dropdownwitharrows/images/arrow-toggle.png') 0px 5px  
        no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;

}
.title img{
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.title span{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    float: left;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jhLgZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try
`.title img{
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0px 10px;
}`